# Set Closure Union and Intersection

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$ and $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$

My attempt:
$x\in\overline{A\cup B}$ iff for every open set $U$ containing $x$, $U\cap\ (A\cup B)\neq\varnothing$. This happens iff $(U\cap A)\cup (U\cap B)\neq\varnothing$, and this happens iff $U\cap A\neq\varnothing$ or $U\cap B\neq\varnothing$, and this happens iff $x\in\overline{A}$ or $x\in\overline{B}$, and this is true iff $x\in\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$. So $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$

If $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, which implies $x\in\overline{A}$ and $x\in\overline{B}$ (since closure of $E$ is the smallest closed set containing $E$), so $x\in\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$. This shows that $A\cap B\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$, and since $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are both closed, $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$ is closed. But by definition, $\overline{A\cap B}$ is a subset of every closed set containing $A\cap B$, so $\overline{A\cap B}\subseteq\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}$.

Do my proofs look correct?

Comment: Actually it is $\overline{A\cup B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$ and $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B} \subseteq\overline{A\cap B}$

Comment: what do you mean @swapniel99

Comment: the proofs are excellent.

Comment: I mean question statement might be wrong.

Comment: do you see anything wrong in the proof @swapniel99 ?

Comment: Yup its wrong:  $x \in A \cup B$ iff for every open set U containing x, $U \cap (A \cup B) \not= \phi$
This should be the correct statement.

Comment: I don't follow you @swapniel99.

Comment: @swapniel99 you may be misinterpreting the overline to mean set complementation. It is meant to indicate the closure.

Comment: yes, take for instance, $A=\left(-\infty,0\right)$ and $B=\left(0,\infty\right)$. the last one is really just an inclusion.

Comment: @Max what are you trying to say?

Comment: Oh!! My bad if that is the case. :)

Comment: I was sure that there was written $\overline{A\cap B}=\bar{A}\cap\bar{B}$ as I read the question first but maybe I'm wrong and my eyes have been betraying me... its still early :-)

Comment: The result about intersection has already been discussed here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599460/prove-that-the-closure-of-the-intersection-of-a-and-b-is-the-subset-of-the-inter
The approach given in an answer there uses monotonicity of closure (i.e, $X\subseteq Y$ $\implies$ $\overline X\subseteq \overline Y$). I'd say this approach is a little bit simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is not quite correct. The statement

> $x\in\overline{A\cup B}$

can be expressed as

> for all open $U$ we have $(U\cap A)\ne\emptyset$ or $(U\cap B)\ne\emptyset$

While

> $x\in\overline{A}$ or $x\in\overline{B}$

is

> for all open $U$ is $U\cap A\ne\emptyset$, or for all open $U$ is $U\cap B\ne\emptyset$

The second statement clearly implies the first one, so 
$$x\in\overline A\vee x\in\overline B\implies x\in\overline{A\cup B}$$
In order to show the other direction, I recommend that you try and prove the contrapositive. So you start by assuming that

> there is an open $U$ disjoint to $A$, and there is an open $V$ disjoint to $B$

and then seek to obtain from this the negation of the first statement. Here you will actually need some topology.

Ironically you used topology in the second proof where it can most efficiently be done the way you proved the $\overline{A}\cup\overline B\subseteq\overline{A\cup B}$ direction.